# PowerShell batch rename with regex? Can't figure out the expression

Tags: regex, powershell

So I have a group of files with the following file names:

52 39 118 070 13200 5480.txt 
83 39 010 392 01000 9970.txt 
37 39 880 163 17802 0473.txt

I am trying to rename them to something like:

2012 File Description (52-39-118-070-13200-5480).txt 
2012 File Description (83-39-010-392-01000-9970).txt 
2012 File Description (37-39-880-163-17802-0473).txt

But, I can't figure out what the corresponding regular expression would be, and how to code it into PowerShell.  I see tons of examples to remove spaces or underscores, but nothing to add to a string.

Please note that "2012 File Description" would be constant for all files being renamed.  The only thing that I would like to change is have the original file name moved into the parentheses and change the spaces to dashes.

Thank you.

Comment: If all you're doing is adding a constant phrase to the front of each, wrapping the original name in parentheses, and all have the `.txt` extension, plain old string concatenation would work much better than a regex (and be a lot easier to figure out how to do).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"52 39 118 070 13200 5480.txt" -replace "(.*)(\.txt)",'2012 File Description ($1)$2'
```

gives:

2012 File Description (52 39 118 070 13200 5480).txt

Important: the replacement string is using single quotes, because the dollar sign "$" character needs to be escaped if it appears in a string that is quoted with double quotes.
Alternatively I could have written:

```
"52 39 118 070 13200 5480.txt" -replace "(.*)(\.txt)","2012 File Description (`$1)`$2"
```

Comment: Thank you jon Z.  That worked perfectly!

That said, how could I change the whitespaces to dashes?

ls | %{ren $_ $($_.name -replace '\s', '-')}

I was able to tear that away from another response and modify it.  But how could I nest this function into the one that you described?  In the meantime, I'll run that one first followed by yours.

Comment: ("52 39 118 070 13200 5480.txt" -replace "(.*)(\.txt)",'2012 File Description ($1)$2') -replace "\s",'_'

Comment: This replaces spaces afterwards.  You end up with 2012_File_Description_(52_39_118_070_13200_5480).txt.

Comment: nice catch - try: ("52 39 118 070 13200 5480.txt" -replace "\s",'_') -replace "(.*)(\.txt)",'2012 File Description ($1)$2'

Comment: So, two more quick questions.  
Why are you using " when matching a string, but ' when replacing a string?  
Also, does $1 and $2 work outside the parentheses?  Can I call those variables from outside, and will they carry through to the next -replace command?  I suspect no...Sorry about the structure.  I can't get line breaks working!

Answer (score 8):

You could do it with a one-liner (piping directly to Rename-Item), but for the sake of simplicity I used the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | Foreach-Object{   
   $NewName = '2012 File Description ({0}){1}' -f ($_.BaseName -replace '\s','-'),$_.Extension
   Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $NewName 
}
```

Comment: To deal with filenames that have '[' ']' brackets, instead of `Rename-Item -Path`  use  `Rename-Item -LiteralPath`.  Otherwise Rename-Item cannot find the $_.FullName

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex for this. As Ken says in the comments, you can just use concatenation (which is super easy in Powershell).

Something like:

```
gci Y:\MyFolder -filter '*.txt' | % {rename-item -path $_.fullname -newname "2012 File Description`($($_.basename)`).txt"
```

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know about this, but I think that regex would still have wider application than this, would it not?

I do have one question for you though, why do you have the first $ before ($_ ?  I've been seeing that everywhere and I don't understand it.  If I try to take it out, I get the same result.

Comment: The `$` in a double-quoted string indicates to powershell to interpret what follows as a variable or expression.  You need to use this before returning properties inside strings enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: So when starting off my command with "ls | %{ren $_ $($_.name" why does it work without it?  What would be returned if I didn't have that first $, string?  I assume that the rename command is taking whatever is contained in the variable $_ and then $_.name would remove the name preceding the extension, after which you can further modify or match the output.  But I don't get the logic as to why it works BOTH with and without the $.  Also, how do I add line breaks?  It says on the FAQ that it's a return and two spaces...not working. =/